# Unable to deploy BW6 application in TEA

Tags: maven, github-actions, cicd, tibco-business-works

I am trying to deploy one BW6 application on Tibco Enterprise administrator using GitHub action.

Below is the `dev.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: Tibco Workflow
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [dev]
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [server]
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build BW6 Application
        run: |
          mvn -B -f src/application.name.parent/pom.xml clean package
            
      - name: Creation of app space and app node and deploy
        env:
        run: |
          mvn -B -f src/application.name.parent/pom.xml deploy
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project ee.entInfra.circuitConfigurationMsg.vndrHana.application.parent: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.tibco.bw:ee.entInfra.circuitConfigurationMsg.vndrHana.application.parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.tibco.bw:ee.entInfra.circuitConfigurationMsg.vndrHana.application.parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/ogeenergycorp/ee.entInfra.circuitConfigurationMsg.vndrHana): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) -> [Help 1]

The pipeline is expected to create the appspace and appnode in agent and then deploy the application but it is not failing but not deploying also even not creating appspace and appnode.

Comment: Apparently, you have some credentials (or access) issue that's why you getting Unauthorized (401) error. Have you verified it? Are you able to make it work from your local machine?